# Should I use PIG to load data into HBase from HIVE or is there a better way?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hbase, apache-pig

I have to load data into HBase table from HIVE.
I know that there are various ways to do this, for example:

- Generating CSV from HIVE and then converting it to HFile using bulk load to load the data
- Using MapReduce to generate HFile
- Using PIG script to generate and load HFile
- Or is there a direct converter available?

Can you please guide me by recommending the best approach to follow?

We are not using phoenix for this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HBASE integration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration#HBaseIntegration-Usage):

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_table_1(key int, value string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "xyz");
```

then load your data into the Hive table, will also load HBase  since is the same table.

Comment: Is this SERDE is a part of Hive distribution?

Comment: It is, see https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/b099e5b9c1a40bf7aac686cc88803eeb888ac76c/hbase-handler .The jar has to be added to classpath, read the linked documentation.

Comment: Thank's a lot for the solution I am able to load data into HBase using the solution you provided.
Are there any limitations to this solution?

Comment: I'm more of a Hive dev rather than user and unfamiliar with HBase integration. I recommend to search online for blogs, presentations etc. Eg http://www.slideshare.net/hortonworks/integration-of-hive-and-hbase-12805463 or http://hortonworks.com/blog/hbase-via-hive-part-1/